# Searching Contacts List by Name

Tags: java, android

I've successfully managed to retrieve a user's phone contacts in an arrayList and upload it to my app,  where I've also been able to distinguish contacts who have my app installed(users) and those who don't have it yet. I've been trying to implement a search functionality where a user can search for a contact by name but I've not been getting any results.

Anyone who can kindly advise on how to go about it?

Also, I would like to sort the arrayList of contacts such that those who have the app installed appear at the top of the recyclerview, arranged in alphabetical order, and those who dont have it appear after the last app user, also arranged in alphabetical order? The whole contacts list is already arranged in alphabetical order as at now by use of Collections.sort();
Here is what I've tried so far.

```
ArrayList<UserObject> userList, contactList;
List<UserObject> filteredList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_contacts);

    //adding the filteredList

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    mUserList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userList);  //recyclerview
    mUserList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mUserList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    mUserList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUserListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false);
    mUserList.setLayoutManager(mUserListLayoutManager);
    mUserListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(userList, filteredList);
    mUserListAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    mUserList.setAdapter(mUserListAdapter);

    search = findViewById(R.id.searchh); //search is an Edittext
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            filteredList.clear();
            String name = search.getText().toString();
            for (UserObject userObject : userList){
                if (userObject.getName().contains(name)){
                    filteredList.add(userObject);
                }
            }
            mUserListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

//my UserListAdapter

```
public class UserListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<UserObject> userList;
    List<UserObject> filteredList; //the filteredList
    private Context context;
    private static final int TYPE_ONE = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_TWO = 2;
    public UserListAdapter(ArrayList<UserObject> userList, List<UserObject> filteredList){
        this.userList = userList;
        this.filteredList = filteredList;
    }

    //some more code

    //BindViewHolder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
            case TYPE_ONE:
                initLayoutOne((ViewHolderOne) holder, position);
                break;

            case TYPE_TWO:
                initLayoutTwo((ViewHolderTwo) holder, position);
                break;

                default:
                    break;
        }
    }

    //case one
    private void initLayoutOne(final ViewHolderOne holder, final int position) {
        holder.mName.setText(userList.get(position).getName());
        holder.mPhone.setText(userList.get(position).getPhone());

        //more code

    });
    ...
}
```

Let me know if there is any additional info that I should add to help everyone understand the problem better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please say what is your problem first? And please specify whether you can use Kotlin or not?

Comment: Hello Saeed, I want to search through the userList which is an arrayList containing all the user phone contacts. How can I go about it?  I'd really appreciate if you give the solution in Java since I'm not that savvy with Kotlin. Anything else you want me to add in the code section ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a copy of the original list. Simply because you don't want to lose your objects if your a constraint is added and removed:

```
List<UserObject> filteredList = new ArrayList();
```

and you show this list in your RecyclerView (or ListView):

```
adapter.setItems(filteredList)
```

Then in the textWatcher you will filter the original list and add the corresponding items to the filteredList and you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged():

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           String name = search.getText().toString();
           filteredList.clear();
           for (UserObject userObject : userList){
               if (userObject.getName().contains(name)){
                   filteredList.add(userObject);
               }
           }
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Do not forget this line
        }
```

**---------EDIT---------**

1- Remove the filtered list from adapter. No need for that.

2- In your activity initialize your adapter as follows:

```
mUserListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(filteredList);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Saeed. Your solution looks like the ideal solution to the problem. However, after modifying my code as advised, still cant get the desired results. Let me post it, including the adapter. Where could i be going wrong? Please advise

Comment: I've edited the code part of the question showing  how I've implemented the changes you advised. Kindly advise where I could be going wrong. Thanks a  bunch in advance

Comment: @EzraRaleigh I edited the answer. I guess you are good to go now.

Comment: I've removed the filteredList from UserListAdapter class and initialized the adapter  as youve shown in edit 2 but am getting an error that UserListAdapter
(ArrayList<UserObject>)
in UserListAdapter cannot be applied
to
(ArrayList<UserObject>,
java.util.List<me.gudy.asapp.UserObject>)

Comment: @EzraRaleigh I have edited the code snippet in my edit section. please replace it with your code. I'm sorry i forgot to edit the code I copied from your Activity.

Comment: You can also 1-2 line this with Java 8 streams

Comment: @Joe Yes this is possible with streams. Although this one was easy to grasp.